# how to handle passwords with python3 and tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, password-protection

I am trying to make a Tkinter app in python3 to send mails using user and password (module `MIME`). I would like to handle the password securely, but I don't know exactly how and I don't get the point of some questions I have seen.

If I ask the users to write their password, I store it in a variable for the connection and after, I delete it from memory, is it ok? Something like this:

```
password = input('Write your password')
# here the program to send mails (connection with server)
password = None
del(password)
```

Of course, if someone has all the control of my computer, it could easily take the password before I delete it from memory, but that would always be the case right? Even if I encrypt it.

Comment: Yes, if someone can read your computer's memory then you've already lost. There's no point in encrypting this password.

Comment: There's not much purpose deleting the password from memory, I don't believe it really serves any. You also would have to make sure the password and username are accurate, so how are you going to do this without the passwords stored anywhere to validate?

Comment: Then similar programs usually handle the password like this? There isn't any better way to handle it? I thought deleting it not to stay in memory for a lot of time (but I guess it is not really necessary)

Comment: if you're worried about something like that you can encrypt the password, that way it will look like a random binary blob in memory